# Node.js: Bad Request when exporting Google Doc with REST API

Tags: node.js, drive

I'm trying to export multiple Google Docs from a folder with the Drive REST Api. In the following code, 'fileId' is set to a specific fileId (and it works perfectly!):

```
var service = google.drive('v3');
fileId = <file_id>
dest = <local_file>

service.files.export({
    fileId: fileId,
    mimeType: 'text/plain',
    auth: <auth> 
})
.pipe(dest);
```

However, when I nest this in a loop in order to export multiple files like so:

```
var service = google.drive('v3');
fileId = <file_id>
dest = <local_file>

service.files.list({
    auth: <auth>,
    pageSize: 1,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id)"
}, function(err, resp) {
    if (err) { return err; }

    var files = resp.files

    for (var file of files) {
        var fileId = file.id;

        service.files.export({
            fileId: fileId,
            mimeType: 'text/plain',
            auth: auth
        })
        .pipe(dest);
    }
});
```

I'm given the following error:

```
{ [Error: Bad Request]
  code: 400,
  errors: 
  [ { domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest',
      message: 'Bad Request' } ] }
```

And for the life of me I can't figure out why. Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!